# How to update list in python from user entered value in last item

Tags: python-2.7

This I tried

```
aList = ['Q', '0006','005C', '0078','0030','0033', '0041','0041', 'ONE_OF', '20' ]
print aList
removeItem=aList.pop()
print removeItem
print aList
a=raw_input("enter the values ")
add=aList.append('a')
print aList
```

I am getting output is ['Q', '0006','005C', '0078','0030','0033', '0041','0041', 'ONE_OF', 'a' ]

I want output['Q', '0006','005C', '0078','0030','0033', '0041','0041', 'ONE_OF', 'a' ]
instead of 'a' in last item should show user entered value in a list

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. You are appending a value like the title of your question.

Comment: I have list ['Q', '0006','005C', '0078','0030','0033', '0041','0041', 'ONE_OF', '20' ] and I wanted to update list in last item by entered value in alist

Comment: Oh! I get what you wanted, but it was already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean

```
aList.append(a)
```

You don't need to assign this to `add` by the way.

If you want to change the current last element to the user input, you don't have to `pop` and then `append`. Just do

```
a = raw_input("enter the values ")
aList[-1] = a
```